# Unable to create copy Case owner look up field onto a custom lookup field

Tags: custom-field, lookup, sobject

Is there any possibility to create the custom field like case owner of standard field.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to do it by writing apex code which will copy the value of the Case Owner field to your custom lookup field.

One approach I tried was to create a Text formula field. The formula field would copy the case owner ID (user or queue) and create a hyperlink to the record. Steps are
1) create the formula field. 
The formula I used was IF( NOT( ISBLANK( Owner:User.Id ) ) ,  HYPERLINK( 'PUT YOUR Org URL here'+Owner:User.Id ,  Owner:User.FirstName)  ,  HYPERLINK( 'PUT YOUR Org URL here'+Owner:Queue.Id ,  Owner:Queue.QueueName ) )

You can either hard code the URL like I did for the purpose of this sample, or use this [Salesforce Success post](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000huVAAAY) to craft a generic base url

[image: lookup field]

2) test it out. If you click on the formula field, it will take you to the User/Queue owner record detail page.
[image: case page snapshot]

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, It's not possible to Lookup(User,Queue) fields.Please vote for below idea.

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BrmkAAC

[image]